# How the client knows when the access_tokens expired and should use the refresh_token?

Tags: oauth-2.0

According to [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework (#RFC-6749), Section 1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5):

> (E)  Steps (C) and (D) repeat until the access token expires.  If the
> client knows the access token expired, it skips to step (G);
> otherwise, it makes another protected resource request.

But, how "the client knows the access token expired"?. I mean, who should cares about that step? Me (my client app) or the oAuth2 framework implementation i'm using? Is this step automatically performed by the oAuth 2 implementation or I have to deal with this in my code?

Can someone point me some example showing this step in practice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The client may have gotten a hint from the Authorization Server when getting the `access_token` in the Authorization Response since there's an optional (recommended) parameter `expires_in` that should be used for that, see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2.

However, in all cases the Client needs to be prepared to deal with invalid access tokens anyway by using the `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token` or by redirecting to the Authorization Server if applicable.

Upon using an expired `access_token` the Client should get an error response from the Resource Server as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3.1, so an HTTP 40x with error code `invalid_token`. That is how the client knows that it should get a new one.